# CURL not working but ping and nslookup yes working with local DNS server Ubuntu16.04

Tags: dns, curl, bind, url

We are working with Bind server on Ubuntu 16.04.
We are unable to *curl* because DNS resolution but *ping* and *nslookup* are working from Ubuntu16.04 client.

Client - `ping`:

```
root@app-01:~# ping -c1 nightly.dev.project
PING nightly.dev.project (10.110.2.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.110.2.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.03 ms

--- nightly.dev.project ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.036/1.036/1.036/0.000 ms
```

Client - `nslookup`:

```
root@app-01:~# nslookup nightly.dev.project
Server:     10.110.1.3
Address:    10.110.1.3#53

Name:   nightly.dev.project
Address: 10.110.2.1
```

Client - `curl`:

```
root@app-01:~# curl -kv nightly.dev.project
* Rebuilt URL to: nightly.dev.project/
*   Trying 10.10.10.24...
* Connected to proxy.dev.com (10.10.10.24) port 8080 (#0)
> GET http://nightly.dev.project/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: nightly.dev.project
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< Content-Length: 1082
<
<HTML><HEAD>

<TITLE>Network Error</TITLE>

</HEAD>

<BODY>

<FONT face="Helvetica">

<big><strong></strong></big><BR>

</FONT>

<blockquote>

<TABLE border=0 cellPadding=1 width="80%">

<TR><TD>

<FONT face="Helvetica">

<big>Network Error (dns_unresolved_hostname)</big>

<BR>
```

Client - `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` :

```
nameserver 10.110.1.3
nameserver 10.110.1.2
search dev.project
```

Client - `/etc/nsswitch`:

```
#hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
hosts:          dns files
networks:       files
```

BIND server - `/etc/bind/named.conf.options` :

```
options {
    #dnssec-validation auto;
    dnssec-validation no;
    dnssec-enable no;
    allow-recursion { any; };
    allow-recursion-on { any; };
    allow-query { any; };

    auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the proxy - `proxy.dev.com` couldn't resolve the DNS record.
Hoping this answer would help to someone who has this unique situation - All the client configurations and DNS machines are right but the proxy not.